# Empty Lists In new class

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I have the code below. Class1 assins the values to the lists(list1, list2,list3). When using these lists inside Class2, the print statement used as a test inside the `calc` function prints a empty list '[]' instead of the data that was stored inside it in Class1. So the calcuation will also return a empty value.

```
    class Class2(Class1):
        def __init__(self, Class1):
            self.arg1 = Class1.arg1
            self.arg2 = Class1.arg2
            self.arg3 = Class1.arg3
            self.arg4 = []

        def calc(self, Class1):
            for row in Class1.arg1:
                self.arg4.append(Class1.list2  + Class1.list3)
                print(Class1.arg1)
            return self.arg4    

    cInput = Class1([],[],[])            
    Test = Class2(cInput ).calc(cInput)
```

Below is my Class1 and a example of how I populate the list(Class1 functions correctly)

```
class Class1:
  def __init__(self, list1, list2, list3):
    self.arg1= list1
    self.arg2= list2
    self.arg3= list3

def getList1(filename1):
    with open(filename1, "r") as csv1  
        csvReader1 = csv.DictReader(csv1)
        list1= []
        for row in zip(csvReader1):  
          list1.append((row1["arg1"]))

        return list1
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @DennisPatterson How do I get the values I assigned from class1 into class2 instead of empty lists

Comment: How does your ``Class1`` look like?

Comment: @DocDriven added Class1 example function

Comment: in `getList1` You are populating `list1` then returning it. Are you then maybe adding the values of that list to self.arg1, or did you just forget to do that, hence resulting in your problem?

Comment: @DennisPatterson When I call the getList1 method I am filling it using list1 = getList1("filelocation"

Comment: @Liights Yes but what's the point if you never update `self.arg1`. You can change `list1` as much as you like it won't change `self.arg1` unless you do so yourself. Let me explain more: In class2, you are assigning it's attributes to the value of **Class1.arg1** not `list1`, which is more of a local variable that never gets out of Class1. What goes from Class1 to Class2 is `self.arg`, and that you never change. You only change `list1`, and that does not change `self.arg1`

Comment: @Liights Something else I just noticed. In your code you are making Class2 inherit from Class1. So now any property in Class1 is also in Class2. No need for you to do much manual copying.

Comment: @DennisPatterson What would be the correct way to update self.arg1 instead of just list1?

Comment: @Liights just do `self.arg1.extend(list1)` at the end when you've finished populating `list1`

Comment: @DennisPatterson I forgot I had a line that first_Object = Class1(list1, list2, list3), would this be a correct way of doing it?

Comment: @Liights That's okay but if you are so intent on manually copying variables from class1 to class2, then you want to do:
`list1 = getList1("filelocation") |

self.arg1.extend(list1)`
And the same for 2 and 3. (the " | " means new line since this is a comment) :)

Comment: @DennisPatterson adding self.arg1.extend(list1) creates another issue. I have a function outside of Class1 that I call to then call every individual function inside of Class1(thats where those two previous lines I mentioned are contained), meaning it wont have access to 'self'

Comment: @Liights then you have to pass to it self. You see that this gets complicated and messy, but that is what OOP inheritance does behind the scenes. That is why it is simply easier to make Class 2 a child of Clas1 than all this mess

Comment: @DennisPatterson What would I change to accomplish that?

Comment: @Liights look at the upvoted answer.

Comment: @DennisPatterson Although that answer solves alot of issues, my lists still appear to be empty. I must be missing something from somewhere

Comment: @Liights Ok i will wright a clear answer for you. Maybe you can then accept that as this question has been going for too long

Comment: @Liights Tell me if this works. I think this is what you meant. If not - explain anything to me. Im with you here all day :) Also please read the explanation to understand whats going on

Comment: @Liights did my answer help?

Comment: @DennisPatterson Yes, currently working though applying those changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you want to do is after getting `list1` from the file, add it to `self.arg1`
Make `Class2` inherit everything so you can call from it directly

```
class Class1:
    def __init__(self, list1, list2, list3):
        self.arg1= list1
        self.arg2= list2
        self.arg3= list3

    def getList1(self,filename1):
        list1 = [1,2,3,4]

        self.arg1.extend(list1)
        return list1

   # another function def getList2(self, filename): ...

   # and the last function def getList3(self, filename): ...


class Class2(Class1):
    def __init__(self, list1, list2, list3):
        super().__init__(list1, list2, list3)
        self.arg4 = []

    def calc(self):
        for row in self.arg1:
            self.arg4.append(self.arg2 + self.arg3)
            print(self.arg1)
        return self.arg4

def populate():
    cInput = Class2([], [], [])
    list1 = cInput.getList1("filename")
    #Do the same with list2 (list2 = cInput.getList2("filename")
    #Do the same with list3 (list3 = cInput.getList3("filename")

    Test = cInput.calc()
    print(Test)

populate()
```

Class2 has everything Class1 has, including the getList methods. So what happens is when you make an instance of Class2, it automatically makes an instance of Class1 and adds it to Class2 (does that make any sense?)

So now, Class 2 will have arg1, arg2, arg3, and arg4. You call getList for each of arg1, 2, and 3, and they become populated. You then call calculate to populate arg4.

Comment: This is a lot of detail and working! thanks also to @DocDriven for his answer

Answer (score 0):

You can fill Class1 with getList1. In your exemple you just initialise it with empty lists.

Comment: When I call the getList1 method I am filling it using list1 = getList1("filelocation")

Answer (score 0):

I think there's some confusion of how to use inheritance in Python. When inheriting from a class, the child class naturally has access to its parent class' variables. There's no need to manually copy it within the `__init__` function. You can simply call the constructor of the parent via `super()` and reuse it for the child.

```
class Class1:

    def __init__(self, list1, list2, list3):
        self.arg1 = list1
        self.arg2 = list2
        self.arg3 = list3

class Class2(Class1):

    def __init__(self, list1, list2, list3):
        super().__init__(list1, list2, list3)
        self.arg4 = []

    def calc(self):
        for row in self.arg1:
            self.arg4.append(self.arg2 + self.arg3)
            print(self.arg1)
        return self.arg4

cInput = Class2([], [], [])

Test = cInput.calc()
```

I hope the code clears up some of the confusion. One last bit though: did you try to make your `getList1` method static? This way, you will get an error when declaring the function without the `self` keyword.

Comment: After making those changes and running the print still prints []

Comment: This is expected behavior. When creating a class instance, you initialize all its variables to be empty array. When you call the function ``calc``, it skips the for loop as ``arg1`` has no elements to iterate over. It returns the empty list of ``arg4``. If you want to change that, just use non-empty lists in the constructor.

Comment: Shouldn't the lists be populated from Class1, so the lists in the constructor shouldn't be empty?

Comment: No, which line makes you think that?